# How to customize Traefik error pages on docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, server, url-routing, traefik

Here is my case, I have an environment of let's say 2 docker containers:

- Javascript application
- Traefik

While JS app is building, container is "not available yet". So traefik will display a 502 bad gateway or a 404 not found standard page.

Is there a way to cutomize those pages?
In order to display a more user-friendly page?

I've dug the traefik documentation, but without success

Comment: Traefik does offer an error-middleware, error pages aren't hosted in traefik, they will be served by an external service - check https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/errorpages/

I am preparing an example and a formal answer if you allow me ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traefik provides error pages middleware

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/errorpages/

Error pages should be served by another traefik service

This is defined by using the following labels on the error handling container

```
# Dynamic Custom Error Page for 5XX Status Code
labels:
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-errors.errors.status=500-599"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-errors.errors.service=serviceError"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-errors.errors.query=/{status}.html"
```

and define which middleware will use on the app container:

```
labels:
- "traefik.http.routers.backend-router.middlewares=test-errors-middleware@docker"
```

This is a basic example that might help you to achieve what you want

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
services:
  errors:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./errors.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/errors.conf
      - ./500.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/500.html
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.errors-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.errors-router.rule=Host(`error.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.errors-router.entryPoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.errors-middleware.errors.status=500"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.errors-middleware.errors.service=errors-service"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.errors-middleware.errors.query=/{status}.html"

  backend:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./backend.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/backend.conf
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.backend-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-router.rule=Host(`test.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-router.entryPoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-router.middlewares=errors-middleware@docker"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.4
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command:
      - --accessLog=true
      - --api=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=default
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.traefik-service.loadBalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-router.rule=Host(`traefik.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-router.entryPoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-router.service=api@internal"
```

`errors.conf`

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri =500;
  }
}
```

`backend.conf`

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    return 500;
  }
}
```

`500.html`

```
<h1>This is broken - HTTP 500 SERVER ERROR</h1>
```